# Ceph- list object in a RADOS block device

Tags: file, object, block, ceph

My question is quiet simple: is it possible to list files that are in a block device?

For instance, if a create a new pool :

> ceph osd pool create myPool

and inside this pool I add a RADOS block device :

> rbd create myBLock -p myPool --size 1024

On a ceph-client I do:

> sudo rbd map myBlock -p myPool
>
> sudo mkfs.ext4 -m0 /dev/rbd/rbd/myBlock
>
> sudo mkdir /mnt/ceph-block-device
>
> sudo mount /dev/rbd/rbd/myBlock /mnt/ceph-block-device
>
> cd /mnt/ceph-block-device

I put some files in the block

> touch myfile.txt
>
> touch hello.txt

How on a osd/mon node can I see thoses files and where they are stored?
I know that :

> ceph osd map -p myPool object1
> works perfectly, but How can I see the complete list inside the pool myPool?

Regards,

Ghislain

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cannot

Long answer: there no concept of "file" in RADOS block device. It is called "block device" for a reason - it keeps just bunch of consecutive blocks with data. What is inside of these blocks is not a concern for a block device. That's your file system driver job to represent these blocks with data as a "file system" you can browse through. In your case "mkfs.ext4 -m0 /dev/rbd/rbd/myBlock" creates ext4 file system on top of the RBD. And only when you do "mount /dev/rbd/rbd/myBlock /mnt/ceph-block-device" you instruct the system to treat RBD as a file system. Take it away and your file system is no more than just a sequence of blocks with bytes in them.

It is similar to having a file system on a normal hard drive. Get a new hard drive, create a partition, format a file system as ext4, write some files, take the hard drive to the system which does not support ext4 and ask yourself the question "How on a  can I see thoses files and where they are stored?" and the answer will be the short answer above: "you cannot"